# How to ssh a gce VM from another gce VM

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, centos7

I've created two GCE VMs.
storm1:10.128.0.4
storm2:10.128.0.5

Now I want to ssh `storm1` on `storm2`.

When `ssh 10.128.0.5` on `storm1`, I got info `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)`.

What're the steps to achieve this? or some tutorials?

Previously, I've known how to ssh a linux VM from my local computer.

Answer (score 0):

- Step1: Apply a **OpenSSH public key** to your **GCP Console project or instance**
  ([Refer to: Adding or removing project-wide public SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#project-wide))

  - For example, using Putty Key Generator to generate OpenSSH public/private pair keys.
    [image]
  - Add the generated **OpenSSH public key** to **SSH keys** (**not** Metadata) in GCP console.
    [image]
- Step2: Copy the **OpenSSH private key** file to `~/.ssh` folder of `VM storm1`.
- Step3: In a terminal of `VM storm1`, use the `ssh` command and your **OpenSSH private key** file to connect to **your instance** `VM storm2`.
  `ssh -i [PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY] [USERNAME]@[INTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS]`
  ([Refer to: Connecting using third-party tools](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#thirdpartytools))

**Tips:**

- Tips1: If you want to use `ssh 10.128.0.5` directly, not specifying the OpenSSH private key file, you can change the name of OpenSSH private key file to `id_rsa`.
- Tips2: Identity `Putty public key` and `OpenSSH public key`, `Putty private key` and `OpenSSH private key`.

  [image]
- Tip3: In my opinion, the Step1 will result in adding the `OpenSSH public key` to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file of all VMs in the GCP project.

  [image]

  [image]