# Problems connecting one GCE instance to another via SSH

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I am attempting to connect (via SSH) one GCE VM instance to another GCE VM instance (which will be referred to as Machine 1 and Machine 2 from now one).

So far I have generated (via `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/ssh_key`) a public and private key on Machine 1, and have added the contents of `ssh_key.pub` to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on Machine 2.

However, whenever I try to connect them via ssh using the following command: `gcloud compute ssh --project [PROJECT_ID] --zone [ZONE] [Machine_2_Name]` it simply times out (Connection timed out. ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].)

I have doubled checked that each VM instance has plenty of disk space, and their firewall settings are permissive, and OS Login is *not* enabled. I have read through the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47905905/how-to-ssh-a-gce-vm-from-another-gce-vm) but nothing is working.

What am I doing wrong? How do I properly SSH from one GCE VM instance to another?

Comment: Your error message means that nobody is listening on machine 2. Double check on machine 2 that sshd is running and listening on port 22: https://superuser.com/questions/529830/get-a-list-of-open-ports-in-linux. Also try adding the command line option `--tunnel-through-iap` to bypass networking issues. Your changes to authorized_keys might have broken ssh.

Comment: @JohnHanley after running `netstat -lntu` i see that "tcp6 - 0 - 0 :::22 :::* LISTEN" , so seems like port 22 is listening. After adding `--tunnel-through-iap` I get the error " Error while connecting [4033: u'not authorized']"

Comment: That is your problem. The account that you are using with gcloud does not have IAM permission to login to compute engine. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam

Comment: Ok thanks, I will contact my sys-admin and resolve this. If it still does not work I'll reply. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I was having was that each VM was using a different network/sub-network with different firewall configurations. After making one using the same network/sub-network, I was able to easily ssh into one from the other via

`username@machine1:~$ ssh machine2`

Answer (score 0):

I tested the same scenario on my side and I got the same result as you said. Then I ran this command inside the machine to debug the SSH process to try to narrow down the issue:

```
gcloud compute ssh YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME --zone ZONE --ssh-flag="-vvv"
```

Then I got this result:

```
debug1: connect to address 35.x.x.x port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 35.x.x.x port 22: Connection timed out
```

So, means the instance 1 is unable to connect to the external IP address of instance 2. I only added a new [firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) and it works.

After running above mentioned command, if you see any `permission denied` message, it means you did not copy the public key to the source machine properly.

Comment: I got the exact same result, so it's not an issue of incorrectly distributing SSH keys I suppose. What do you mean created a new firewall rule? What exactly did you change? It seems like it's trying to connect on port 22 which is listening. Thanks

Comment: As a test you can create a temporary firewall rule and select 'Apply to all' as the target and select 0.0.0.0/0 as the source IP range (during firewall creation). Then select tcp protocol and type 22. Then click on create button. Also,netstat output shows the port 22 is listening in OS level, not in the GCP side.

Comment: I did exactly that but unfortunately I'm getting the exact same error - a Connection timeout.

Comment: Any ideas why the new firewall rule isn't helping? @Milad

Comment: Make sure about the priority in your firewall rules. Rules with lower numbers get prioritized first. Default is 1000. Also, I recommend you to have a look at this document about some common [SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#top_of_page) issues.